# Combining different authentication types for your endpoints with spring security

Tags: rest, spring-boot, security, oauth-2.0, basic-authentication

I've been scavenging around the internet for information about multiple security configurations regarding combining oauth and basic authentication.

I'm not sure it's really what I want, but I decided to do some research to figure out weather it was a good idea or not.

The question is really simple. Can you combine Oauth authentication and basic authentcation in your spring boot application. So that some endpoints uses one type of authentication and other end points uses another type of authentication.

and does it make sense to do so?

The idea behind it is that I want to have heavy(oauth authentication on my endpoints if another party is calling my application) however if i'm calling my endpoints through a frontend application that I control. Should that then still use Oauth, or would basic authentication be alright?

to sum up. Is it possible to have "/getCustomers" secured by oauth, and "/ping" completely open or with another authentication type.

I hope this makes sense, I kinda trying to figure out what I want with this and if it even makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

> to sum up. Is it possible to have "/getCustomers" secured by oauth, and "/ping" completely open or with another authentication type.

To sum up, yes you can.

You can configure multiple entry points with same http element, you can configure different http elements, and you can even configure several WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter according to spring security reference documentation.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#multiple-httpsecurity